# LinkerD file based service discovery not working

Tags: service-discovery, linkerd

I'm not able to use file based service discovery in LinkerD.

Here is my directory structure:

```
[root@ip-172-23-1-207 aman]# ls
config disco index.html linkerd-1.0.2-exec upload
```

LinkerD config file looks like this:

```
[root@ip-172-23-1-207 aman]# cat config/linkerd-fs.yml
namers:
- kind: io.l5d.fs
  rootDir: disco

admin:
  ip: 172.23.1.207
  port: 8888

routers:
- protocol: http
  dtab:
        /svc => /#/io.l5d.fs ;
  servers:
  - port: 7777

telemetry:
- kind: io.l5d.recentRequests
  sampleRate: 1.0
```

Here's, my copy of initial dcs config file:

```
[root@ip-172-23-1-207 aman]# cat disco/dcs
172.23.1.211 1212
172.23.1.133 1212
172.23.1.207 1212
```

Now, if I add any new server under dcs for example:

```
[root@ip-172-23-1-207 aman]# cat disco/dcs
172.23.1.211 1212
172.23.1.133 1212
172.23.1.207 1212
172.23.1.130 1212
```

The requests are not getting routed to the new VM unless I restart the LinkerD. Please suggest what could be wrong here?

Comment: Hmm, everything with your linkerd config looks correct to me, and testing locally I can see the file-system namer picking up the new instance and sending it traffic, without any need to restart linkerd. Linkerd uses Java's [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) API to watch for changes to the filesystem. What filesystem are you using? The only explanation that I can think of is that maybe you're on a filesystem that's not compatible with the WatchService API.

Comment: I'm using default Unix File System and the Operating Systems is CentOS. My initial thought was also around WatchService, but there's nothing in the linkerD log that will help me identify the issue.
Do we need to specifically start/stop the WatchService? I presumed LinkerD installation would have taken care of that.